# How to multi clipping object in eyeshot

Tags: eyeshot

I found the clipping object in the eye shot sample, but there was no multi-clipping.

Also, I need to clip the x-plane and y-plane, but I can't find this information.

How can I multi-clip with an eye shot?

Also, how can I change the angle of clipping?

There are only examples of clipping creation in the demo.

design.ClippingPlane1.Edit(null);

Comment: I want the functionality provided in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBXH7HiaWQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add a toggle button to your app and do this and toggle it three times manually adjusting plane angle.

```
    private int count;

    private void buttonEditClipPlane_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentWorkspace is Design d)
        { 
            d.ActionMode = actionType.None;

            if (d.ObjectManipulator.Visible)
            {
                d.ClippingPlane1.Apply();
                d.ClippingPlane2.Apply();
                d.ClippingPlane3.Apply();
            }
          
            switch (count)
            {
                case 0:
                    d.ClippingPlane1.Edit(Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Red));
                    d.ClippingPlane1.CappingColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    d.ClippingPlane2.Edit(Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Green));
                    d.ClippingPlane2.CappingColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    d.ClippingPlane3.Edit(Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Blue));
                    d.ClippingPlane3.CappingColor = Color.Blue;
                    break;
            } 

            d.Entities.Regen();
            d.Invalidate();
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but instead of manually adjusting the angle, I want to change the angle automatically.

Comment: I solved it using ClippingPlane (Plane, Boolean).